# Only 1 of 3 JavaScript files load when using <ltng:require> and afterScriptsLoaded event not firing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service

**Background**

I am trying to use the [PageDown](https://github.com/SalesforceBobLightning/pagedown) JavaScript library:

- [Markdown.Converter.js - (click to view source)](https://github.com/SalesforceBobLightning/pagedown/blob/master/Markdown.Converter.js)
- [Markdown.Editor.js - (click to view source)](https://github.com/SalesforceBobLightning/pagedown/blob/master/Markdown.Editor.js)
- [Markdown.Sanitizer.js - (click to view source)](https://github.com/SalesforceBobLightning/pagedown/blob/master/Markdown.Sanitizer.js)

Note: the above links to a forked repo. This is the original [StackExchange PageDown](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown) repo.

---

But when I try and load 3 JavaScript files using `<ltng:require` code below:

```
<aura:component controller="MyController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"
access="global">

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                       $Resource.Markdown_Converter,
                       $Resource.Markdown_Sanitizer,
                       $Resource.Markdown_Editor
                       )}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />

<!-- other code -->

</aura:component>
```

But only the first static resource loads and the `afterScriptsLoaded` method never fires.

**Controller.js**

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log("doInit 1");
    },
    afterScriptsLoaded: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log("afterScriptsLoaded 1");
    }
})
```

Each JavaScript static resource file has:

- `cacheControl` of `Public`
- `contentType` of `application/javascript`.

**Markdown_Converter.resource-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <cacheControl>Public</cacheControl>
    <contentType>application/javascript</contentType>
</StaticResource>
```

And there are no errors in the console:

[image]

And Network show no 404/403/401's

[image]

**Questions**

1. What is causing this?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: Robs, try checking the network tab for any 404/403/401 errors. Also, check the static resource content type to make sure they are application/javascript. Your code looks just fine from here. I'll try to reproduce, but might take a moment.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've added console log and network log

Comment: @sfdcfox Any thoughts on further lines of investigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+Robs, thanks for your detailed description, I was able to load all three files without any problem.

1. Upload the three files in static resources (I used the UI).
   [image]
2. Create a component using your unaltered code (and add it to a page):
   [image]
3. Load the page an look that all files are loaded in developer console.
   [image]

My advise is to look in Setup > Static Resources, and maybe add the files from there, and see what you get.

Comment: I added the files via SFDX and VS Code. Do you think that is the issue?

Comment: OK. I deleted them and re-added and it works now. The only difference I can see is the content type is `text/javascript` rather than `application/javascript`

Comment: @Robs Can you tell me what decides the content type? It happens sometimes but how to control this.

Comment: @VivekMakkar I created the static resources as `application/javascript` via VS Code, whereas SF created them as `text/javascript` when I uploaded via Setup.

Comment: This is strange, text/javascript is legacy and application/javascript is "modern" mime type. We'll look into it.